# Can't open my Java project in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am working with JDA+NetBeans. Suddenly my project refuses to open. I get the error

> Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to look for UTF-8 characters (such as umlauts etc.) and delete/replace them; you could also try to open the file with another editor, save it and try Netbeans again.

Comment: not bad advice. The other thing I was thinking is he originally created some pages in ISO-8859-1/Windows-1252, and then switched the editor to UTF-8....hence the invalid bytes

Answer (score 0):

open your files in notepad++ choose

```
Format -> convert To UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

If the project get not opened, one of the project configuration files in the nbproject folder are corrupt. You can do:

1. Create a new project and copy the sources to the new project (and all the other things you did in the old project)
2. Open the corrupt project thru the Favorites window. Have a look into the nbproject files, maybe save again the files when opened from the Favorites window.